Hell is it retribution or restoration?
Is the concept of hell (this word is not in scripture) a place for retribution or restoration by Christ because He reconciled ALL TO Him?

hi carey welcome to BH_SC. The NT has γέεννα=hell, ἀποκατάστασις=restoration, ἐκδίκησις=vengeance but are those close enough to what you mean? Presumably the first one isn't - but why not?

Could you pls cite a scripture that relates to your question?

Col 1:20 says "...things in earth, or things in heaven."  It doesn't mention reconciling things in hell.

Hi Carey, welcome to Stack Exchange! As others have mentioned, this site is all about the exegesis of specific texts. Please take the Site Tour to learn how it all works here. For now we've Closed this Question - if you have the same or a similar question that is framed in response to analysis of a specific text, feel free to Edit this Question to include it and we'll reopen it for you.
